# No injector factory bound for Class

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am very new to using dagger2. I am getting                                                                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class NotificationsFragment and looked at multiple sample projects and can't seem to figure out a solution

FriendAlertApplication.kt

```
class FriendAlertApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector{


@Inject lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DaggerApplicationComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    setupTimber()
}

private fun setupTimber() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }
}

override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
    return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector
}
}
```

ApplicationComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(   ActivityBuilderModule::class,
                            ApplicationModule::class,
                            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance fun application(application: Application): Builder
    fun build(): ApplicationComponent
}

fun inject(app: FriendAlertApplication)

}
```

ApplicationModule.kt

```
@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(HomeActivitySubComponent::class,
                            TestActivitySubComponent::class))
open class ApplicationModule {

@Provides
@PerApplication
fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
    return application
}
}
```

ActivityBuilderModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(HomeActivityModule::class))
abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity

@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(TestActivityModule::class))
abstract fun bindTestActivity(): TestActivity


 }
```

HomeActivitySubComponent.kt

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(HomeActivityModule::class,
                            FragmentBuilderModule::class))
interface HomeActivitySubComponent : AndroidInjector<HomeActivity> {

@Subcomponent.Builder
abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<HomeActivity>()

}
```

NotificationsFragmentSubComponent.kt

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(NotificationsFragmentModule::class))
interface NotificationsFragmentSubComponent : 
AndroidInjector<NotificationsFragment> {

@Subcomponent.Builder
abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<NotificationsFragment>()

}
```

HomeActivityModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class HomeActivityModule {



}
```

FragmentBuilderModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuilderModule {

@PerFragment
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(NotificationsFragmentModule::class))
abstract fun bindNotificationsFragment(): NotificationsFragment

}
```

NotificationsFragmentModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class NotificationsFragmentModule {

@PerFragment
@Provides
internal fun provideNotificationView(notificationsFragment: 
NotificationsFragment): NotificationsContract.View {
    return notificationsFragment
}

@PerFragment
@Provides
internal fun provideNotificationsPresenter(mainView: NotificationsContract.View,
                                           getNotifications: GetNotifications, mapper: NotificationMapper):
        NotificationsContract.Presenter {
    return NotificationsPresenter(mainView, getNotifications, mapper)
}

}
```

HomeActivity.kt

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Inject lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

private var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView? = null
private var containerLayout : FrameLayout? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

    containerLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.containerLayout);

    bottomNavigationView?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}


override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.menu_broadcast ->
                Log.d("","")
        R.id.menu_myplace ->
            Log.d("","")
        R.id.menu_friends ->
            Log.d("","")
        R.id.menu_notifications -> switchToNotificationsFragment()
    }

    return true
}

fun switchToNotificationsFragment() {
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerLayout, NotificationsFragment().instantiate(Bundle())).commit()
}

override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
    return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
}
}
```

NotificationFragment.kt

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment(), NotificationsContract.View {

@Inject lateinit var notificationsPresenter : NotificationsContract.Presenter
@Inject lateinit var notificationsAdapter : NotificationsAdapter
@Inject lateinit var mapper : NotificationMapper

private var notificationsRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

override fun setPresenter(presenter: NotificationsContract.Presenter) {
    notificationsPresenter = presenter;
}

fun instantiate(@Nullable arguments: Bundle): NotificationsFragment {
    val notificationsFragment = NotificationsFragment()
    notificationsFragment.setArguments(arguments)
    return notificationsFragment
}

override fun showProgress() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun hideProgress() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun showNotifications(notifications: List<NotificationView>) {
    notificationsAdapter.notifications = notifications.map { mapper.mapToViewModel(it) }
    notificationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    notificationsRecyclerView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

override fun hideNotifications() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun showErrorState() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun hideErrorState() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun showEmptyState() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun hideEmptyState() {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)

    notificationsRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.notificationsRecyclerView)
    setupNotificationsRecyclerView()


    return view;
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    notificationsPresenter.start()
}

private fun setupNotificationsRecyclerView() {
    notificationsRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    notificationsRecyclerView?.adapter = notificationsAdapter
}

}
```